# 'Maximising interpretative power entails maximising consistency strength'?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, mathematical-philosophy, foundations

I'm hoping there is a clear mathematical answer to this question (hence asking it here) rather than anything more exegetical (in which case it's presumably not appropriate for this site).

In his paper '[Gödel's Program](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Esteel/papers/godelsprogrampub.pdf)', Steel gives the current (at least in 2012) state of play in the quest to 'decide mathematically interesting questions independent of $\textsf{ZFC}$ in well-justified extensions of $\textsf{ZFC}$' [p1], and offers his view of how a solution might proceed, via the framework of the consistency strength hierarchy and his multiverse language.

Steel's key maxim, taken from epistemology, is that our best set theory ought to 'maximise interpretative power' [p2], in that the language and theory we choose ought to be able to describe and answer questions about as much of mathematics as possible. Later in the paper he notes that 'maximising interpretative power entails maximising consistency strength' [p11].

I wasn't sure exactly what this final remark went -- does he just mean that the (apparent) linearity of the consistency strength hierarchy indicates that the higher we climb the more questions we will be able to answer (and thus is relevant to the second conjunct in his glossing of 'maximising interpretative power' in my paragraph above), or is there are more concrete mathematical interpretation of what he means by this? I'm thinking in particular of the sort of thing discussed in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126002/interpretability-and-consistency-strength).

Comment: It means exactly what it says. Paraphrasing: the more theories a given theory $T$ interprets, the more theories are consistent relative to $T$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek something like if $T$ inteprets $T'$, then $\operatorname{Con}{T} \to \operatorname{Con}{T'}$?

Comment: Yes. ----------

Comment: @EmilJeřábek cheers -- feel free to type up a very brief answer and I'll accept